MySQL Previous Results Query Returning Incorrect Values
I am using a query that I found on Stack Overflow to return a row in my table when a production counter resets at the start of a shift. However, it is also returning rows when the production counter changes from hundreds to thousands, thousands to ten thousands, etc.
So, if my counter values are as follows:



ndx
counter




1
700000


2
252


3
2178


4
4101


5
6027


6
7953


7
9876


8
11769


9
13695


10
15618



The query that I used is:
SELECT results.* FROM table AS results WHERE
results.counter < (
    SELECT prevs.counter FROM table as prevs WHERE
        (prevs.ndx = results.ndx - 1)
)

I'm expecting to get back:



ndx
counter




2
252



But the query returns the following:



ndx
counter




2
252


3
2178


8
11769




Change the counter column's data type to integer. Or if you absolutely can't, cast it to integer before comparisons.

The issue is coming because your query checks if the current row's counter is less than the previous row's counter.
And this condition is satisfied not only when the counter resets but also when there are smaller counter increments (like due to rolling over from hundreds to thousands etc).
To identify only rows where the counter "resets", you need to add an additional condition that defines a "reset."
This amendments should work -


SELECT results.* 
FROM table AS results 
WHERE 
    results.counter < (
        SELECT prevs.counter 
        FROM table AS prevs 
        WHERE prevs.ndx = results.ndx - 1
    )
    AND results.counter < 1000;



